# Group rows in Oracle using PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below 2 tables which i want to display like shown result

Data Table 1

```
id    col1      col2
t1    data1     data2
t2    data3     data4
```

Data Table 2

```
idOfTable1   col3       col4
t1           data5      data6
t1           data7      data8
t1           data9      data10    
t2           data11     data12
```

Expected result 
Want to display the id value in first row only for the common rows
Result DataTable after Join of 2 tables on id column
How can i achieve in Oracle

```
idofTable1      col1       col2       col3        col4
t1              data1      data2      data5       data6
                                      data7       data8
                                      data9       data10
t2              data3      data4      data11      data12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(T1.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T2.COL3) = T1.ID 
            THEN NULL
       ELSE T1.ID END AS ID,
       CASE WHEN LAG(T1.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T2.COL3) = T1.ID
       THEN NULL
       ELSE T1.COL1 END AS COL1,
       CASE WHEN LAG(T1.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T2.COL3) = T1.ID
       THEN NULL
       ELSE T1.COL2 END AS COL2,
       T2.COL3,
       T2.COL4
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.idOfTable1
ORDER BY T1.ID, T2.COL3
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=183f7292becd8b2aaa30b768bac9f418) is the fiddle.

Comment: This is not correct unless the outer query has an `order by`.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  Also, the subquery is not needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Completely agreed and edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a AS
 (SELECT t2.*,
         row_number() over(PARTITION BY idoftable1 ORDER BY col3) r2
    FROM t2),
b AS
 (SELECT t1.*,
         row_number() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) r1
    FROM t1)
SELECT id,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4
  FROM b
 RIGHT JOIN a
    ON a.idoftable1 = b.id
   AND a.r2 = b.r1
 ORDER BY a.idoftable1,
          a.col3
```